# How do I add a click handler to a new element when I create it?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do I add a click handler to a new element when I create it? This is what I have tried, but it does not work as expected:

```
DeCheBX = $('MyDiv').insert(new Element('input', {
    'type': 'checkbox',
    'id': "Img" + obj[i].Nam,
    'value': obj[i].IM,
    'onClick': SayHi(this)
}));
document.body.appendChild(DeCheBX);
DeImg = $('MyDiv').insert(new Element('img', {
    'id': "Imgx" + obj[i].Nam,
    'src': obj[i].IM
}));
document.body.appendChild(DeImg);
}
SayHi = function (x) {
    try {

        if ($(x).checked == true) {
            alert("press" + x);
        }

    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("error");
```

Comment: FYI -- this was a perfectly valid question with a really horrible title originally and pretty bad formatting (which has been fixed thanks to @John Rasch).  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Agreed (but I can't vote for reopening yet). It looks more like Vicky doesn't understand what information goes where and how to format code on this site. @vicky: please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-do-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user-work-the-official-faq and especially http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-get-my-code-blocks-formatted

Answer (score 2):

The way you are adding the handler, the function is actually being invoked when you create the element. When you write SayHi(this) it actually runs the function with the current value of this. What I'd suggest is wrapping the invocation of the handler into an anonymous function defined when you create the element. That way the SayHi code won't actually be executed until the click handler is invoked. Replace this:

```
'onClick': SayHi(this)
```

with

```
'onClick': function() { SayHi(this); }
```

Comment: won't work - this will be the caller of the anonymous function - which is window

Answer (score 0):

```
'onClick': SayHi.bind(this)
```

Hi there!

Just use '.bind' before your params! An event handler has to be a function, not the return of your function. Create a functions that will have the params you want baked in by using .bind.

-Rob

Comment: assumes use of prototype - which is ok for questioner - but maybe others are looking for generic solution

Comment: The question is tagged as prototype.

Answer (score 0):

*this* will be window because that is the invoker of the onclick function.

bind will fix this if you are using prototype or other libraries but for those who want a native solution, you need to break up your code a little to simplify it:

```
var myElem = new Element('input', {
    'type': 'checkbox',
    'id': "Img" + obj[i].Nam,
    'value': obj[i].IM
}

myElem.onclick = function() {sayHi(myElem )};

DeCheBX = $('MyDiv').insert(myElem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myElem = new Element('input', {'type': 'checkbox','id': "Img" + obj[i].Nam,'value': obj[i].IM }).observe('click',sayHi);
$('MyDiv').insert(myElem);

SayHi = function () {
try {

    if (this.checked == true) {
        alert("press" + this);
    }

}
catch (e) {
    alert("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

with prototype will something like this

```
$('id').observe('click',function(event){
      alert("make something cool");
}.bind(this))
```

or the second option

```
Element.observe('id',"click",function(){
    alert("make something cool");
}.bind(this))
```

both works... cheers =)